# How to reference parent using child's text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In jQuery, how can I reference only the element with the child's h2 equal to "Recipe Test 2"?

```
<li class="sfnewsListItem">
            <h2 class="sfnewsTitle">
                <a href="#">Recipe Test 1</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="sfnewsMetaInfo">May 23, 2011</div>            
</li>
<li class="sfnewsListItem">
            <h2 class="sfnewsTitle">
                <a href="#">Recipe Test 2</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="sfnewsMetaInfo">May 23, 2011</div>            
</li>
<li class="sfnewsListItem">
            <h2 class="sfnewsTitle">
                <a href="#">Recipe Test 3</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="sfnewsMetaInfo">May 23, 2011</div>            
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
$('a:contains("Recipe Test 2")').closest('h2');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XhXva/).

References:

- [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var parnt =$("h2:contains('Recipe Test 2')").closest("li");
```